# Erro de cast ao rodar o serviço rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

Estou tendo esse erro:

> The 'Qtde' property on 'ItensLib' could not be set to a
>   'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Single'.

O que pode causar isso?

```
[Table("ITENSLIB")]
    public class ItensLib
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_ITENSLIB")]
        public int IdItensLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_PRODUTO")]
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        [Column("PRODUTO")]
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE")]
        public float Qtde { get; set; }
        [Column("UNITARIO")]
        public float Unitario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTO")]
        public float Custo { get; set; }
        [Column("MINIMO")]
        public float Minimo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL")]
        public float Total { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public float CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("FABRICANTE")]
        public string Fabricante { get; set; }
        [Column("ULT_CONDICAO")]
        public float UltCondicao { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Vencido")]
        public byte FlagVencido { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA")]
        public float VendaVista { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA")]
        public float MargemAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA")]
        public float QtdNegAvista { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO")]
        public float VendaPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO")]
        public float PmPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO")]
        public float MargemPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO")]
        public float JurosPrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO")]
        public float QtdePrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_VISTA_ANT1")]
        public float VendaVistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float MargemAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_NEG_AVISTA_ANT1")]
        public float QtdeNegAvistaAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDA_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float VendaPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("PM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float PmPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("MARGEM_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float MargemPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float JurosPrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
        [Column("QTDE_PRAZO_ANT1")]
        public float QtdePrazoAnt1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Essa é minha chamada

```
public class ItensLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLibDTO libDTO = new ItensLibDTO();

        [Route("itens/{id}")]
        public ItensLibDTO getItensLib(int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                }).FirstOrDefault();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Meu serviço

```
[RoutePrefix("api/itens")]
    public class ItensController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLiberacao itens = new ItensLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public HttpResponseMessage getItensLiberacao(int id)
        {
            var _itens = contexto.ItensLibs.Where(it => it.IdOrcamento == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _itens);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi alterando o método. Não entendi, mas deu certo:

```
[Route("itens/{id}")]
        public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib(int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
```

E claro a chamada

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<ItensLibDTO> getItensLiberacao(int id)
        {
            return itens.getItensLib(id).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta aqui:

```
var _itens = contexto.ItensLibs.Where(it => it.IdOrcamento == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Na hora de traduzir o SQL para C#, você esta atribuindo um valor `null` para a propriedade QTDE que não aceita esse valor.

```
[Column("QTDE")]
public float Qtde { get; set; }
```

Faça esse ser um `Nullable<float>` que vai funcionar.

```
[Column("QTDE")]
public float? Qtde { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sim, é nullable(string), passei tudo para string na DTO, devido a um problema que debatemos bem aqui e ainda não encontrei solução, a não ser fazer essa "gambi", passando os campos float e double para string. Inclusive você participou bastante nessa situação, o qual me deu muita luz sobre diversos assuntos.

Comment: Erro meu, não vi que era string e string aceita null normal. Desculpe. Tem certeza que é o mesmo erro que continua? Não é um novo?

Comment: Cara, só não entendi se de um jeito funciona e outro não. Pra mim assunto resolvido, mas entendimento é fundamental, para não ocorrer e ficar patinando num problema que não é problema em si, e sim um erro lógico. Vou continuar minha leitura no assunto.

Comment: É assim: Quando você faz uma consulta sem o Enumerable.Select() você traz todas as linhas do banco, algo como um `SELECT * FROM ITENSLIB WHERE...`. Então se você não tiver um valor na linha ele vai trazer nada e vai quebrar sua propriedade, é diferente de fazer um `contexto.ItensLibs.Select` e não trazer essa propriedade do banco, nesse caso vai ser criado uma entidade com seu valor default (que no caso do float vai ser 0). No caso da DTO não é um problema ser nulo porque string em C# aceita nulo por padrão.

Comment: Bem, ok, valeu pela explicação. Entendi o porquê das coisas, nesse contexto, mas a questão do cast, quando eu terminar esse projetinho de 15 dias que tá mais de um mês, vou voltar ao assunto.

Answer (score 1):

No SQL o tipo `float` é equivalente a `double`.

Já no .NET o apelido (alias) `float` é equivalente a `single`.

[C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.110).aspx)

Então, aparentemente no seu banco de dados, a coluna `Qtde` é `float` mas no C# deve ser `double` ao invés de `float` pois eles são apelidos para tipos diferentes.

Comment: MurariAlex, nesse caso e em outros posts meus sobre o assunto, eu fiz a troca de float para `Single` ou `double` e o erro persistia. Inclusive possuo alguns posts sem solução aqui, sobre **CAST**, tive que transformar em meu DTO todos os **floats** e **doubles** em **string** para que pudesse funcionar o meu serviço.

Comment: Mesmo trocando no C# a propriedade `Qtde` de `float` para `double` não funciona? Se puder, faça esse teste e mostre qual a mensagem de erro ele retorna.